# Using annotate in django and counting number of sections in a box

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model:

```
class ShipmentItem(models.Model):
    shipment_box = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    section = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=[(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "D")],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=1,
    )
```

I am writing a query on the ShipmentItem model...

```
self.queryset.annotate(
    quantity=Count("section", filter=Q(shipment_box=F("shipment_box")))
).order_by("shipment_box", "section")
```

For some reason, quantity invariable comes back as `1` no matter if I know that there is more to quantify

How do I get annotate to work?

Comment: What do you want to annotate? `Count` is used to get the count of related models. In your model `section` is a `CharField` (for some reason even though you store numbers in it i.e. 1, 2, 3 (the second value in the tuples are the display value)).

Comment: I want to annotate quantity as a field describing sections, like where multiple instances of ShipmentItem are in section 1 and also happen to be in box 3, so quantity could be like 5 @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: I can give you an answer, but I need to know what you need: You will be annotating EVERY instance of ShipmentItem with the same count of its kind of section though, is that what you desire? Or do you need JUST the counts for each section?

Comment: i want to annotate every item in the queryset with the count of its kind, yeah @Yokhen

Comment: @GeneralBear I assume your situation to be something like this: You have shipment boxes all of which have 4 sections. An item can be put in some shipment box in a particular section. For this scenario your model schema is not very appropriate (it is not normalized, the answer below by yvesonline attempts to normalize your models). The best way to make your models would be something like 1) A model `ShipmentBox` which stores details of a shipment box. 2) A model `ShipmentItem` which has a foreign key to `ShipmentBox` and a field that shows which section it is put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with what you have designed so far, I think what you are looking for is to use the [Window](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) function:

```
ShipmentItem.objects.annotate(
    quantity=models.Window(
        expression=models.Count('section'),
        partition_by=[models.F('section')],
    ),
).order_by("shipment_box", "section")
```

Bear in mind though, that your current design only allows one section per `ShipmentItem`, so if you need to allow an item to have multiple sections, you will have to switch to a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship like @yvesonline's answer suggests.

Comment: Thank you! With slight modification (I added to partition_by to include shipment_box as well) that worked perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

`annotate` works on related models, you don't have any relations in your models.

I don't know you exact scenario but I think you should rethink the way you structure / set up your models.

Imagine revised models for your scenario like this:

```
class ShipmentSection(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D')], null=True, blank=True, default=1)

class ShipmentItem2(models.Model):
    shipment_box = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    section = models.ManyToManyField(ShipmentSection)
```

Now if I do the following:

```
>>> item = ShipmentItem2(shipment_box=1)
>>> item.save()
>>> section_1 = ShipmentSection(section=1)
>>> section_1.save()
>>> section_2 = ShipmentSection(section=2)
>>> section_2.save()
>>> item.section.add(section_1)
>>> item.section.add(section_2)
>>> item.save()
>>> ShipmentItem2.objects.all().annotate(quantity=Count(F('section')))[0].quantity
2
>>> item.section.count()
2
```

As you can see via the `ManyToManyField` it's even easier to get to the count by using the shortcut `count()` method on the set itself.